# I have recently installed ubuntu after i erased my hdd and I dont know if the hdd has only one partition now

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I am new to Ubuntu(coming from windows), and I don't know if the install went right: I understand that by default there should be 2 partitions after the install so i run this command

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and this is the output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 159.9 GB, 159905567744 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19440 cylinders, total 312315562 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b9862

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2          501758   312313855   155906049    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5          501760   312313855   155906048   83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: 159.6 GB, 159645696000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19409 cylinders, total 311808000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 157.4 GB, 157449977856 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19142 cylinders, total 307519488 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 2143 MB, 2143289344 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 260 cylinders, total 4186112 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sda: 8032 MB, 8032092160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 976 cylinders, total 15687680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xefb71902

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63    15687679     7843808+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Can somebody tell me if something went wrong just by looking at this output ? I want to know if there are at least 2 partitions or I have to reinstall Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You have two hard disks that seem to have valid partitions.

Because of:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2          501758   312313855   155906049    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5          501760   312313855   155906048   83  Linux
```

your have a HDD (`/dev/sdb: 159.9 GB`) that have only 2 partitions: `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2`. `/dev/sdb2` is an extended partition that is subdivided in only one logical partition: `/dev/sdb5`.

Because of:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63    15687679     7843808+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

you have disk (most probably a flash drive - `/dev/sda: 8032 MB`) with one partition: `/dev/sda1`.

To understand better how exactly are partitioned your drives, install and use [GParted [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/).

Comment: then everything is alright, thank you for the answer